# How to enable a full-functional screen keyboard on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, onscreen-keyboard

I need a screen keyboard with shift, ctrl, and etc, but the screen keyboard on ubuntu 20.04 doesn't support them. I use screen keyboard on a tablet.